# Get content inside element tags when parsing

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Given that my code:

```
browser.get(s_page_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
s_image_element = soup.find('a', {'id': 'angle-3'})
s_image_href = s_image_element['href']
s_image_url = "http://www.zappos.com" + s_image_href
s_title_element = soup.find('h1', {'class': 'banner'})
print s_title_element
```

currently produces the following output:

```
<h1 class="banner">
<a href="http://couture.zappos.com/a-testoni">a. testoni</a>
<meta content="a. testoni" itemtype="brand">
<a href="/p/a-testoni-sport-nappa-calf-sneaker/product/8835012"><span class="ProductName" itemprop="name">Sport Nappa Calf Sneaker</span></a>
</meta></h1>
```

How would I get the text in `<a href="http://couture.zappos.com/a-testoni">a. testoni</a>` i.e. `a. testoni` and `<span class="ProductName" itemprop="name">Sport Nappa Calf Sneaker</span>` i.e. `Sport Nappa Calf Sneaker`?

I've tried the following so far:

```
print s_title_element['a']
```

But get the following error message:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'a'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print s_title_element.get_text(strip=True,separator=" " )
```

`get_text` will concatenate all the text in the tag object. `strip=True` will strip the whitespace in the beginning and end

```
def get_text(self, separator="", strip=False,
             types=(NavigableString, CData)):
    """
    Get all child strings, concatenated using the given separator.
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I get a space between the words, because what I get is `a. testoniSport Nappa Calf Sneaker` at the moment

Comment: @methuselah it's the source code, what matters are the parameters.